How to manage B2B app distribution in Apple Business Manager with unregistered entities(Client neither registered as ADP or Apple Business Manager)?
We are currently facing an issue with distributing a white-labeled healthcare app on iOS. Here’s the scenario:

App Background: We have an existing healthcare app under the iOS developer account of Company A (let’s call it XYZ Holdings).
White-Label App: We created a white-labeled version of this app for another entity (let’s call it ABC Services).
App Store Rejection: The white-labeled app was rejected with the reason: "The app must be published under a seller and company name that is associated with the organization or company providing the services. In this case, the app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the ABC Services name."

To comply with this guideline, we decided to use B2B distribution via Apple Business Manager. However, ABC Services has not registered as an Apple Developer Program (ADP) member or in Apple Business Manager yet.
We need clarity on the following points:

Enrollment in Apple Business Manager: Should XYZ Holdings or ABC Services enroll in Apple Business Manager?
Distribution Process: If XYZ Holdings enrolls in Apple Business Manager, how should the white-labeled app be distributed to ABC Services?
Steps for ABC Services: What steps should ABC Services follow if they need to enroll in Apple Business Manager or ADP to facilitate this distribution?

We are looking for detailed steps and best practices to ensure smooth distribution and compliance with Apple's guidelines. Any insights or experiences with similar scenarios would be highly appreciated.

Is ABC services intending to distribute the app to their own employees or to the general public? Assuming that they want to distribute it to their employees then they need to sign up for Apple Business Manager and provide you with their Apple Business Manager organisation id.  You can then add this in the distribution section of your app in App Store Connect.  The best way for ABC to distribute the app to their uses is for the devices to be enrolled in an MDM.  If the devices are not MDM managed then they will need to distribute redemption codes to the users

Be aware that the downside of distributing redemption codes is that the app is "owned" by the Apple ID that redeems the code. So if an ABC employee redeems the code with their personal Apple ID then they will continue to have the app if they leave ABC Services.
